# How to change the Release icon? [VS .NET C++-CLI]

Tags: visual-studio-2012, icons, c++-cli, release

I know this is a simple question, but it's being a headache for me.

I have my C++-CLI application on VisualStudio written with .NET framework. I only want to generate my .exe file with a custom icon.

Searching on the internet I only could be able to find the next solution:

Poject node -> Properties -> Application tab -> And here I can set the icon.

But my Visual Studio does not count with that 'Application' tab (I have VS2012).

How can I set the icon to my .exe file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are using the C++ IDE, it assumes you are doing resources the C++ way.  If you don't have an app.rc project item yet then add it with Project > Add New Item > Resource > "Resource File (.rc)".  Activate the resource editor so you can add an icon by simply double-clicking it.

Comment: It worked for me! Thanks, Hans!!